# how can I change the content of a fixed header between sections of a site

Tags: html, css

I have a site with a single page. The site has seven sections.
The header is fixed, but I would like to change some of its contents in each of the sections .
Any suggestion?
Hugs from Sao Paulo / Brazil

My code

```
<div class="section"id="home">
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top grid_12 ">
    <div class="container col-xs-2 fundo_branco ">
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <!-- responsive nav button left-->
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle-left float-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
              </button>
              <!-- /responsive nav button left-->
        </div>
        <!-- main nav  left -->
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left sobe" role="navigation">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><img src="assets/img/logo_menu.png" alt=""></li>
                <li ><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#welcome">WELCOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#top-drinks">TOP DRINKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#help-blog">HELP!BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#franchise">FRANCHISE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /main nav left-->
    </div>
   <div id="header" class="container col-xs-3"> <!-- Sugestion@Snappawapa-->
          <h1>Section 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container col-xs-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- responsive nav button right -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapsea">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></i>
            </button>
            <!-- /responsive nav button -->
        </div>

        <!-- main nav right-->
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapsea navbar-left desce" role="navigation">
            <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#features">
                        <img src="assets/img/bloco1.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /main nav right-->
    </div>        
</header>
</div>
```

I need in each section change the contents of this div in section #welcome

```
<div class="container col-xs-3">
     <h1>Welcome!</h1> 
</div>
```

Code Section #welcome in this page

```
   <div class="section" id="welcome">

            <script>
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "<h1>Welcome</h1>";
    </script>
```

This is works, but in the section home changes also.
I want to keep this header for each section. Example:

in section welcome

```
header=<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

in section top-drinks

```
header=<h1>Top drinks</h1>...
```

Comment: I don't see any sections in your page, but that could be just a matter of interpretation.

Comment: In <li><a href="#welcome">WELCOME</a></li> goto         <div class="section" id="welcome">
           <h1>Welcome</h1>

Comment: @MrLister, I think you are confusing the english word "section" with the HTML section element.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript would probably help you out. Give it an id:

`<div id="header" class="container col-xs-3">
     <h1>Este conteúdo muda em cada seção!!!!</h1> 
</div>`

Then you can use some JavaScript to change the contents of it:

`document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "<h1>New Header</h1>";`

You could use different events on elements in the page to change it by putting that code in a function:

HTML:

`<li ><a href="#home" onClick="changeHeader('<h1>New Header</h1>')">HOME</a></li>`

JavaScript:

`function changeHeader(newStuff){
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = newStuff;
}`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Snappawapa, i change my question, because your answeer help me part partly....